# Use of su command in c code

Tags: c, linux, shell

I want to use a command in my c code. This command works properly when i am a superuser in terminal (using su) but does not work when I use sudo. I gathered that I can use system() in my c code as follows

```
system("su -c \"mycommand\"")
```

myCommand is a command that sends input to some device, like (echo 1 > mydevice)

I compiled my c code using gcc and run the output file. The trouble is, it wants root password from terminal when it comes to this line. 
Is there a way I supply password programatically? I did it before with sudo command with -S option, but sudo command does not work for this case. If it is not possible, is there another way to deal with this?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Never do that. It is horrible. And explain what `mycommand`  does. Do you know about [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) ?

Comment: @mafso it means I still get error about permission when I use sudo.

Comment: You could configure `/etc/sudoers` to avoid `sudo` asking any password; of course, this is a significant security risk.

Comment: Which password should the user be asked for? The root password or the one of the user running the program? How should the user be asked? Via `stdin` or from the terminal? What do you mean by supplying the password prgrammatically? Did your software read it from the user before? And, as Basile's asked, what does `mycommand` (and your program) do?

Comment: I edited my question, thanks for all comments

Comment: Do you mean the `-s` (lowercase!) option instead of `-S`? That would explain most of my confusion.

Comment: @mafso no, I only said that to explain I could fix it by that if sudo is working without permission errors.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, I didn't know about setuid, but can you explain why the other method is horrible?

Comment: You are bypassing all the Unix security barriers. You should make your device writable by you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead,

```
system("sudo sh -c \"mycommand\"");
```